# VBA if～else if をそれぞれ一行で記載する場合の書き方

Tags: vba

下記のようにif～else ifを各ブロック1行で記載しておりますが、
「コンパイラエラー：End ifに対応するifブロックがありません」となってしまいます。
どのように修正すればよいでしょうか、またはこのような書き方はできないのでしょうか。

```
    If value = "1" Then requestType = "01"
    ElseIf value = "2" Then requestType = "12"
    ElseIf value = "3" Then requestType = "14"
    ElseIf value = "4" Then requestType = "16"
    ElseIf value = "5" Then requestType = "18"
    ElseIf value = "6" Then requestType = "19"
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thenの後で改行しないとだめなようです。

```
    If Value = "1" Then
        requestType = "01"
    ElseIf Value = "2" Then
        requestType = "12"
    ElseIf Value = "3" Then
        requestType = "14"
    ElseIf Value = "4" Then
        requestType = "16"
    ElseIf Value = "5" Then
        requestType = "18"
    ElseIf Value = "6" Then
        requestType = "19"
    End If
```

どうしても、条件と実行文を見た目１行にまとめて書きたいなら、以下のように書けばよいと思います。

```
    If Value = "1" Then requestType = "01" _
    Else: If Value = "2" Then requestType = "12" _
    Else: If Value = "3" Then requestType = "14" _
    Else: If Value = "4" Then requestType = "16" _
    Else: If Value = "5" Then requestType = "18" _
    Else: If Value = "6" Then requestType = "19"
```

Answer (score 0):

この記事の仕様記述を見ると：
[If...Then...Else ステートメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement)

> 構文
>
> ```
> If condition Then [ statements ] [ **Else ** elsestatements ]
> ```
>
> または、ブロック形式の構文を使用できます。
>
> ```
> If condition Then
> [ statements ]
> [ ElseIf condition-n Then
> [ elseifstatements ]]
> [ Else
> [ elsestatements ]]
> End If
> ```

質問のソースは、まずこの1行で完結していると考えられます。
つまり、この行は暗黙の裡に行末に`Else`や`End If`が存在するものと扱われるのでしょう。

```
If value = "1" Then requestType = "01"
```

それに続く以下の文は1行目とは別の文と考えられるので、`If`で始まっていないからエラーになるのでしょう。

```
ElseIf value = "2" Then requestType = "12"
ElseIf value = "3" Then requestType = "14"
ElseIf value = "4" Then requestType = "16"
ElseIf value = "5" Then requestType = "18"
ElseIf value = "6" Then requestType = "19"
End If
```

こちらにすると通ります。
最初の`If`文および成立する部分の実行行は2行に分けなければならないけれども、`ElseIf`の部分はまとめて1行に書けるようです。

```
If value = "1" Then
    requestType = "01"
ElseIf value = "2" Then requestType = "12"
ElseIf value = "3" Then requestType = "14"
ElseIf value = "4" Then requestType = "16"
ElseIf value = "5" Then requestType = "18"
ElseIf value = "6" Then requestType = "19"
End If
```

---

質問のような使い方をするなら、`Select Case ステートメント`を使った方が綺麗に書けるのではないでしょうか。
[Select Case ステートメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)
[Select Case ステートメントの使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-select-case-statements)

応用するとこちらになるでしょう。

```
Select Case value
    Case "1"
        requestType = "01"
    Case "2"
        requestType = "12"
    Case "3"
        requestType = "14"
    Case "4"
        requestType = "16"
    Case "5"
        requestType = "18"
    Case "6"
        requestType = "19"
    Case Else:
End Select
```